# MySQL - Join these subqueries into a single query

Tags: mysql, join

**Overview**

I have a MYSQL table with an *id*, a *text field* (description) and *n* boolean fields.

For each Item AND for each boolean value that is true, I need to **group_concat** the description (text).

---

**Example:**

Suppose the following Table called 'Item':

**Item**

- id
- description
- hasGoodHealth
- hasMaintenanceIssues
- has....

The solution I've come up with is the following: 2..*n* queries, where *n* is the number of boolean columns/variables on the table, example:

```
Select item.id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(item.description,",") AS report
FROM Item as item
WHERE item.hasGoodHealth is True AND item.description > ''


Select item.id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(item.description,",")  AS report
FROM Item as item
WHERE item.hasMaintenanceIssues is True AND item.description > ''
```

---

**Question**

How to join these queries into a single query?
Supposing the "Item" table has a fixed and known fields of boolean values.

Comment: what's the point of grouping by if you only select the rows with true values

Comment: Let me test this without "groupBy". i will let you know

Comment: You are right, theres no reason for the GroupBy. Let me remove it.

Comment: the group by is actually needed but not for hasGoodHealth and hasMaintenanceIssues. It is needed for item.id

Comment: No, I dont need group for id. It works fine without it.

Comment: how is it possible that "group_concat" works without grouping by ?

Comment: It does. And it is working. Flag more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since item id makes no sense in a query which contains an aggregate function(group_concat)  over the entire set and will return a non determinate value I have dropped it. You can use case statement in group_concat

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(id int,description varchar(10),hasGoodHealth bool,hasMaintenanceIssues bool);

insert into t values
(1,'aaa',1,1),
(2,'bbb',1,1),
(3,'ccc',0,1),
(4,'ddd',1,0),
(5,'eee',0,0),
(6,'',1,1);

select 
         replace(group_concat(case when hasgoodhealth is true then description else 'dummy' end),',dummy','') hasgoodhealth,
         replace(group_concat(case when hasMaintenanceIssues is true then description else 'dummy' end),',dummy','') hasMaintenanceIssues
from t
where description > '';

+---------------+----------------------+
| hasgoodhealth | hasMaintenanceIssues |
+---------------+----------------------+
| aaa,bbb,ddd   | aaa,bbb,ccc          |
+---------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```